# searching from jquery easyUi treegrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I am working with [jquery EasyUi treegird](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/treegrid.php)  and i want to do filtering from the grid.

any one implemented such a functionality from easyui tree grid kindly suggest me or provide me code that how to do filtering using easyui treegrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure If you're still looking, but here's a solution using HTML, Jquery/jeasyui/Ajax and Java:

1. HTML:

   `<html>`
   `<form>`
   `<input id="searchFilter" name="searchFilter" class="required" />`
   `<a href="#" onclick="doSearch()">Search</a>`
   `</form>`
   `<%-- the treegrid (a table) to contain the results --%>`
   `<table id="dgMilestone"></table>`
   `<html>`
2. Jeasyui/Ajax. This is placed in the same file as the HTML code above:

   `<script type="text/javascript">`
   `$('#dgMilestone').treegrid({`
           `url:"yourBean.action?&listAjax",`
           `idField:'id',`
           `refresh:'id',`
           `treeField:'name',`
           `columns:[[`
                   `{field:'name',title:'Name',width:250, rowspan:2, sortable:'true'},`
           `]]`
       `});`
   `function doSearch()` {
           `// get the search parameter`
           `var search = $('#searchFilter').val();`
           `// call your backing bean method, passing the search filter`
           `$('#dgMilestone').treegrid({`  
               `url:'yourBean.action?&_eventName=searchAjax&searchFilter='+search
           });`
       `}`
   `</script>`

I haven't included the backend stuff, but, in your backing bean, you would have a method called searchAjax which gets the searchFilter parameter and then calls the service layer, passing the parameter as an argument to the search method.

The results (a collection) are returned from the service layer to the backing bean which converts them to JSON (also not shown) and then doSearch() re-draws the treegrid to display the found results